# Fullcalendar.js - titleFormat in Week view

Tags: fullcalendar

Okay, so in FullCalendar v2.3.1, I'm having trouble formatting the titleFormat for week view. I want to display both ranges like so:

*DD-MMM-YYYY ~ DD-MMM-YYYY*

I looked for possible solutions like putting square brackets (i.e., week: "d MMMM yyyy{ '—' d [MMMM ]yyyy}") but nothing's happening.

Answer (score 1):

in fullcalendar.io v2.5.0 try:

```
views: {
    agendaWeek: {
        titleFormat: '(d MMMM yyyy)'
    }
}
```

Normal brackets did the trick for me. [German date format: '(D.) MMMM YYYY' preserves the dot after each day.]